# button textcolor not changed

Tags: android

```
      button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                button3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.buttonDarkSelected);
                button4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.buttonMediumUnselected);
                button3.setTextColor(R.color.yellow);


        }
    });
    button4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                button4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.buttonDarkSelected);
                button3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.buttonMediumUnselected);
                button4.setTextColor(R.color.yellow);

        }
    });

}
```

I am trying to change Button's background and textcolor clicking in that buttons. the background is fine working fine but textcolor always black (instead I want it be yellow) what's my problem here.

Comment: Have you tried with button4.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW); or button4.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("FFFF00")); ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

button4.setTextColor(getApplication().getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));

This will work to change the text color to yellow

Answer (score 0):

You can see this : 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html

With state list, you can choose differents color for button with differents state.

regards,

Answer (score 0):

define a selector like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#ffffff" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#000000" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#000000" />
<item android:color="#ffffff" />
</selector>
```

save this as xml file (for example btn_text_color.xml)in your *../res/drawable/*
Link it to your button like:

```
android:textColor="@drawable/btn_text_color"
```

For more details on the subject, see the link that @Kentino posted.